# Plot csv - define legend labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I created a csv-file (with pandas and the help of a friend) like the one in the picture.

[image]

Now I need to plot this file. 
The first column is the time and should be used for x data. The rest is y data.

For the legend I just want the first row to be used for the labels, like "T_HS_Netz_03" for the second column.

Could not figure out how to do this.

My first attempt:

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv('file', header=[0, 1], delimiter=';')
ax = csv_data.plot(legend=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.0, 1.0, 0.), loc=3, ncol=2, mode="expand")
plt.show()
```

But this includes the second row in the labels too and the x ticks does not match the data (0.9 - 3.2).

Second attempt:

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv('file', header=[0, 1], delimiter=';')
x =csv_data.iloc[1:, [0]]
y = csv_data.iloc[1:, 1:]
plt.legend()
plt.plot(x, y)
```

This does not show any labels

The resulting plot should be something like

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your cvs file with numpy from example. Then, you can plot columns :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("file", delimiter="", dtype=[("time", "f4"), ("column1", "f8"), ("column2", "f8")])

figure_1 = plt.plot(data['time'], data['column1'])

figure_2 = plt.plot(data['time'], data['column2'])

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('data')
plt.ylabel('time')

plt.show()
```

You should get the good result ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned I managed to plot the file. The problem actually is the labeling of the lines. In the legend i want them to be "T_HS_Netz_03" and "T_NS_EZA_direkt_Trafo". The labels change with different files, as the count of columns does. So a different csv-file could have 3 additional columns with different labels.

Comment: @bademaister I edited my script and plot. But I would like to see your script too ..

Comment: @bademaister I don't know what do you want more exactly with your second script. x and y labels ?

Comment: Exactly. I want the legend to show the corresponding label for each column. What i get with my first attempt is "T_HS_Netz_03, u1. Betrag in p.u.)". The second attempt does not show any label, as i did not provide any. But i don't know how i managed to provide just the first row of the labels. Problem is, i am pretty new to pandas/matplotlib

Comment: I finally tested your code. This does not show any legend for me. The plot itself is correct though.